# How to formalize these proofs and conclusion?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I have these sentences and I have obtained these atoms and solution:

1.- When there is public spending, if the citizens are not satisfied, the banks do not give credits

2.- For there to be public spending, it is necessary for banks to give credits or for companies to earn money

3.- Banks give credits when companies make money, provided citizens are satisfied

4.- So only when there is public spending and citizens are satisfied, companies make money

C: citizens are satisfied
B: banks give credits
E: companies make money
Q: there is public spending

My solution:

```
Proof 1: P→(¬B→¬C)
Proof 2: (B∨E)→P
Proof 3: (E→B)→C
Conclusion: (P∧C)→E
```

Another approach:

```
Proof 1: (¬C ∧ ¬B) → P 
Proof 2: (B∨E) → P 
Proof 3: C → (E → B) 
Conclusion: (¬P∧¬C) → ¬E
```

Why are the premises wrong? I interpret it this way, following the idea of condition and conditioning.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you are trying to do, but note that if citizens are not satisfied, and banks do not give credits, and there is no public spending, but companies make money, then I think all of 1, 2 and 3 seem to be satisfied while 4 is not, so you cannot say that the first three together imply the fourth.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I need to translate these sentences into premises to later solve it. I'm tired now but I also have another answer thinking what you have told me:

Proof 1: (¬C ^ ¬B) -> P
Proof 2: (BvE) -> P
Proof 3: C -> (E -> B)
Conclusion: (¬P^¬C)->¬E

Now makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
Proof 1: P→(¬C→¬C)
Proof 2: (B∨E)→P
Proof 3: (E→B)→C
Conclusion: (P∧C)→E
```

Thanks to everyone who paid attention